# Sublime Text não aparece barra de menu no Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: sublime-text, editor-de-texto

Estou com problema no sublime text
de uma hora pra outra sem perceber, desapareceu a barra menu
alguem ja passou por isso?

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Sublime 2 ou 3? Tente reinstalar.

Comment: Tenta esta dica: https://forum.sublimetext.com/t/top-menu-dissaperared/5448

Comment: opa esqueci de mencionar, é o Sublime 3

Comment: Quando acontece isso comigo, eu maximizo a tela e passo o mouse nessa parte de cima e aparece a barra de menu. Espero ter ajudado,
Abraços!

Comment: @Douglas Reinstalar só por isso?

Comment: @jbueno tentei ete procedimento, mas nada ocorre

Comment: Que procedimento? Reinstalar?

Comment: Usando as teclas Ctrl + Shoft + P e View: Toggle menu

Comment: Outro detalhe, desinstalei e instalei novamente, sem sucesso

Comment: Você dever te configurado para ficar invisível seu menu, aperte apenas a tecla 'alt'. O menu deve aparece, vá em view -> show menu. Pronto, ele ficar habilitado.

Comment: resolvi com o seguinte comando no terminal
initctl restart unity-panel-service

Comment: obrigado pela atenção

Answer (score 2):

Tecle <kbd>Alt</kbd>, isso vai mostrar o menu. Pra deixar ele sempre visível, vá em **View** > **Show menu**.

Geralmente os softwares usam a tecla <kbd>Alt</kbd> pra mostrar/esconder o menu.

Também é possível via comando. Tecle <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>P</kbd>, digite **menu** e aparereça uma opção dizendo **View: Toggle menu**, clique nesta opção.